# Is what I want to make Lardo?

Tags: curing

I have this idea of curing fat that comes from my biltong making. I'm wondering if this would be Lardo and whether it is a good idea?

I want to take a nice piece of pork backfat (or maybe belly) Salt it (2 hours) with koshering salts off course. Use a vinegar bath to get all the excess salt off the fat. Cover it in a good amount of spice over night and then afterwards hang in the dispensary for two weeks.

Is this a good idea? Will this make Lardo? I'm wondering if the vinegar bath that works for the meat will work for the fat. I suspect the vinegar and the fat may not mix well.

Comment: Most lardo recipes call for packing the fat in salt under pressure for 10-14 days before hanging.  My understanding is that the pressure and salt are to extract moisture -- the vinegar is just going to add moisture back in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lardo is cured for longer, then it's hung.

I've used [this recipe from the Belly to Bacon blog](http://frombellytobacon.com/2012/10/09/lardo/) and it works well. Salting for 2 weeks is the minimum. The 30 days in the recipe makes it saltier, but the saltier it is, the longer it stays preserved. The instacure keeps the meat safe from botulism. Don't skip it.

One addition to the recipe: when you hang it to dry in step two, it should be in a curing chamber at 50 to 60 degrees Fahrenheit and 60 to 75 percent humidity.